# Make command failing in RHEL but passes in ubuntu

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, centos

Stuck with weird problem while building image of [Service-Catalog](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/service-catalog) on red hat linux, after running `make` following error occurs while same `make` works perfectly fine on ubuntu. Following is the error

```
sed "s/GO_VERSION/1.12/g" < build/build-image/Dockerfile | \
  docker build -t scbuildimage -f - .
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /root/go_projects/src/github.com/kubernetes-sigs/service-catalog/-: no such file or directory
make: *** [.scBuildImage] Error 1
```

Its failing while executing following line.

```
.scBuildImage: build/build-image/Dockerfile $$(shell sh -c "docker inspect scbuildimage" > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo .forceIt)
    mkdir -p .cache
    mkdir -p .pkg
    sed "s/GO_VERSION/$(GO_VERSION)/g" < build/build-image/Dockerfile | \
      docker build -t scbuildimage -f - .
    touch $@
```

Comment: In some more detail, the error message reveals that it thinks `-` is a file in the current directory, not standard input. I'm guessing you have an older version of the `docker` binary on Red Hat.

Comment: Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26